# How to edit environment of another user from root?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So the issue here is I need to modify the environment of a user, say `ironman` from root. I tried the following:

> su -l ironman -c 'source my_bash.sh'

The `my_bash.sh` just contains a script that modifies some environment stuff but the above doesn't seem to work. When I try to logon to `ironman` and check the environment, it remains unchanged.

Comment: The environment is transient. You could modify their .bashrc file.

Comment: How do you modify the user's environment in `my_bash.sh`? Can you post the code?

Comment: I mean that if you want to change their environment, you need to edit their .bashrc, using vi or whatever, so that the next time they log in, their runtime environment will reflect the change.